# Are there any new/conflicting rules in the Death Note Movies?

Tags: death-note

In a Madman Newsletter talking about the release of *Death Note: Light up the NEW World* in the cinemas it says

> In 2016, society is afflicted with cyber-terrorism. The Death Note is a supernatural notebook that grants its user the power to kill simply by writing a person’s name on its pages. **Six different Death Notes fall to the human world, the maximum number of notes that can exist at once.**

[Online Version](http://madmanonline.cmail20.com/t/ViewEmail/t/35D5C8144924C82C/512EB7B24115E16AD9767B6002735221)

Now I don't recall it ever being said in the anime that there was a limit to the number of Death Notes, however since the new movie is set after *Death Note 2: The Last Name* and it's incompatible with the anime/manga because

> L takes his own life to expose Light as Kira by writing his own name in the Death Note

I am wondering if there were any new or conflicting rules to the Death Note in the Live Action Movies compared to the Anime/Manga.

Comment: Its hard to believe that L will do something like that.

Comment: @LightYagami that is what happened in the Death Note Live movie 1 and 2. The new 2016 version is basically a reboot of the old movie 1 & 2 version by making it a serial.

Answer (score 2):

In the last few episodes, one of the rules does actually say that if the number of death notes in the human world exceeds 6, the 7th note will have no effect until one of the other notes is destroyed or returned to the shinigami world.